# WP admin bar disappeared

Tags: admin-bar

The admin bar suddenly disappeared from the front end side of my site. It is present and works alright at the backend. I thought it could be due to some plugin so I deactivated them one by one and checked . Now all the plugins are deactivated and the admin bar is still missing...My theme does have the `wp_footer()` in footer.php. What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Might be one of 3 things (since you verified a wp_footer)**

1. you set it to not show in your user profile
2. a plugin you installed has a Confliction with it
3. you created a php / js code which produces errors in your wp_footer

**Course of action:**
1. Check you personal user profile backend to see you haven't turned it off
1. turn off all plugin (rename plugins folder temporarily)
2. Activate wp-config errors display on (and check for errors)
   *- Response to this & fix errors.*

Hope this helps get to the root of the problem... Basiclly these
are steps to be taken before asking a question so we could have the
additional information incase this does not solve you issuse.

Best of luck, Sagive

Comment: I should have checked this before..Silly on my part...It was set not to be shown in the user profile as you pointed out. Seems like the plugin I was using to enable front end posting had set that option off. 
Thanks!

Comment: gr8 mate - happy you got it working